# How to 'bind' a formula to a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to apply a custom formula to a filter in Google Sheets. The filter will be that the value of that column (field) is `>2`. Here it is entered in:

[image]

But how do I 'bind' that formula to the field? For example, only rows 5 and 6 should return.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better what you mean by "Binding" If you could also share a sheet that could be copied which showed the current outcome and the one you wish to have that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this formula in `custom formula` section:

```
=A2:A>3
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- why does `A2` work here? As in, doesn't the A2 value change? Or that's just the convention for how Google Sheets does a filter -- it's the first cell underneath the header?

Comment: the custom formula can also be just `=A:A>3` provided Cell A1 is text header(& you wish for it to be visible).

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how `A2:A` works? Or is that kind of an accepted hack or something that works only in the context of a filter formula? For example, when done in the context of a cell it just returns a single scalar (`false`), so how then does it work in a filter formula? https://gyazo.com/38e4003e437d7d95d49581d2f6f3cd74

Comment: I'd go with `filter by condition` is inherently applying an arrayformula logic to the range supplied to the custom formula (https://i.imgur.com/phY6UHr.png)